# What is the actual meaning of "VOIP based app"?

Tags: voip

Everyone says Skype is VOIP based application. Can anyone explain how Skype works on VOIP?

Answer (score 3):

VoIP is a technology that can be used to provide voice communication (in apps for example).
[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html) puts is this way:

> A Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP) app allows the user to make
>   phone calls using an Internet connection instead of the device’s
>   cellular service. Such an app needs to maintain a persistent network
>   connection to its associated service so that it can receive incoming
>   calls and other relevant data. Rather than keep VoIP apps awake all
>   the time, the system allows them to be suspended and provides
>   facilities for monitoring their sockets for them. When incoming
>   traffic is detected, the system wakes up the VoIP app and returns
>   control of its sockets to it.

Basically, it is a group of technologies for the delivery of voice communications over Internet Protocol (IP) networks, such as the Internet.

I do not believe that there is something special about the implementation of Skype, there are lots and lots of VoIP apps out there (Viber, iCall etc.). Have a look at [this Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios) on how to implement VoIP in iOS, scroll down to Providing VoIP Services.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you. Only one complement related to **Skype**: Skype is the best known company of **peer-to-peer Internet telephony**. During a peer-to-peer call, VoIP phones communicate and stream audio directly over IP. It's very convenient, since there's no need for any extra devices/services except for the VoIP application and Internet connection. Users install the app (e.g. Skype) and start to communicate with each other (each other's computer). You can also build your own P2P app using a VoIP SDK (e.g. Ozeki's SDK). Source: http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/p_282-peer-to-peer-voip.html